# How do I configure TypeScript to not compile an imported module?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have this file structure.

```
./
├── src/
│   └── index.ts
└── types/
    └── types.ts
```

index.ts imports from types.ts

types.ts only has type definitions. When I run the tsc command for compiliation. A types.js file is also generated. Can TypeScript ignore the types.ts file when compiling?

```
./
├── src/
    ├── index.js
│   └── index.ts
└── types/
    ├── types.js (not wanted)
    └── types.ts
```

An example of the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["types"]
}
```

I invoke `tsc` in the terminal, root directory.

Comment: That's exactly what the [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) and [`exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) options are for. Please search and read the docs.

Comment: why it's not `types.d.ts` ?

Comment: @Bergi I have been trying to use [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) and [exclude](https://typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) and types.js is still being generated. I thought it would still be generated because index.ts imports from types.ts.

@Dimava I'm not familiar with `file.d.ts`

Comment: @Jonathan Please [edit] your question to show your tsconfig and/or how you invoke `tsc`

Comment: @Bergi done. Thanks.

Comment: Don’t use a declaration file for that. That’s really for libraries

Comment: Use import type… instead

Comment: I assume you're using a native javascript library that doesn't distribute type-definitions. Yes, creating a `types/xxxx/index.d.ts` [should work](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/tsconfig.lib.json#L8) and is the recommended way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting types.ts to types.d.ts solved the problem. As types.ts only contains type declarations, it is known as a declaration file. Please refer to [type declarations | .d.ts files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/type-declarations.html#dts-files) for more information.